# How to split a line on every match reading from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin

A kind of new learner of linux and need your bit of help here.
This code

```
sed 's/regexp/&\n/g' file.txt
```

works only on first match gives the output on first match only and then it stops reading the rest of line.

What if I want to keep on reading the line till end and move the line to new line on every match?

For example I have a log file like the following

```
some text here Critical and some text here Critical and again some text here Critical.
```

I want to break it like the following

```
some text here
Critical and some text here
Critical and again some text here
```

Comment: Just swap `\n` with `&` and say `sed 's/Critical/\n&/g' file`.

Comment: Use the second approach that I have given, it's more portable.

Comment: Thanks, just adding "&" worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use g for changing globally.

```
echo "some text here Critical and some text here Critical and again some text here Critical." | sed -e 's:Critical:\nCritical:g'
```

Eventhough this will work, I would recommend you to use this:

```
echo "some text here Critical and some text here Critical and again some text here Critical." | sed -e 's:Critical:\
> Critical:g'
```

Where > is prompt character. You don't have to use it. You will get it. This is the portable way to use sed to change new lines. All other ways aren't portable.

To read from file:

```
sed -e 's:Critical:\
Critical:g' file
```

Comment: but I need to read the text from file.
       sed 's/Critical/\n&/g' file
the above commaned worked

Comment: You can read text from file using second also. If it works then upvote and accpet. I changed gsed to sed. Both are same in linux.

Comment: @Hamad I added for file also.

Comment: Thanks @Khrm,
I am new to stackoverflow. I was not expecting that quick and accurate help.
Have to say that, really impressed.

Comment: Welcome. Hope you ask and answer more in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Perl one-liner:

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; @y = split(/Critical/, $_); print join("\nCritical", @y) . "\n"'
```

This assumes the contents of file.txt is just one long line like this as you indicated:

`some text here Critical and some text here Critical and again some text here`

output:

```
some text here 
Critical and some text here 
Critical and again some text here
```